# How to execute the GO statement with dynamic count?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, t-sql

How to set dynamic count for `GO` statement?

I am getting the following error:

> A fatal scripting error occurred.Incorrect syntax was encountered
>   while parsing Go.

when I tried to run the below query:

```
Declare @count int
Select @count=COUNT(*) From Users 

Insert Into #DummyUsers 
Select * from Users where UserName = 'Sachin' 

GO @Count
```

But the same is working fine when I use the below query with hard coded count.

```
Declare @count int
Select @count=COUNT(*) From Users 

Insert Into #DummyUsers 
Select * from Users where UserName = 'Sachin' 

GO 5
```

Appreciate your suggestions if you have any idea on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you simply want to insert a repeated row you could use a CTE or numbers table.

```
-- Sample data.
declare @Users as Table ( UserId Int Identity, Name VarChar(16) );
insert into @Users ( Name ) values
  ( 'Bob' ), ( 'Carol' ), ( 'Ted' ), ( 'Alice' );
select * from @Users;

-- Load another table with repetitions of a single user.
declare @TempUsers as Table ( UserId Int, Name VarChar(16) );
declare @Repetitions as Int = ( select Count(*) from @Users );
with TempUsers as (
  select UserId, Name, 1 as Repetitions
    from @Users
    where Name = 'Ted'
  union all
  select UserId, Name, Repetitions + 1
    from TempUsers
    where Repetitions < @Repetitions
  )
insert into @TempUsers ( UserId, Name )
  select UserId, Name
    from TempUsers;
select * from @TempUsers;
```

Answer (score 5):

You can't. As soon as SSMS encounters GO the batch is terminated and your variable no longer exists.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use a variable for the `count` parameter to `GO`, but in your example (which may be contrived) you could just join back to `Users` :

```
Insert Into #DummyUsers 
Select U.* from Users U
INNER JOIN Users U2
    ON U.UserName = 'Sachin'
```

Other options:

- Dynaimc SQL (building up SQL by concatenating strings) and executing via `SQLCMD.EXE` or `OSQL.EXE`
- Using a `WHILE` loop with a counter

Comment: Dynamic sql will not work. Go is not a sql server keyword. It is the batch terminator in SSMS. If you put GO in dynamic sql it will not work...unless of course you meant building a long string instead of using GO.

Comment: I clarified that you must use an external program to execute SQL with `GO` in it.

Answer (score 0):

Instead try this.

```
DECLARE @cntr INT=1

WHILE @cntr <= @count
  BEGIN
      INSERT INTO #DummyUsers
      SELECT *
      FROM   Users
      WHERE  UserName = 'Sachin'

      SET @cntr+=1
  END
```

Answer (score 0):

I would just loop it

```
Declare @count int
Select @count=COUNT(*) From Users 

WHILE(@count > 0)
BEGIN
    Insert Into #DummyUsers 
    Select * 
    FROM Users 
    WHERE UserName = 'Sachin' 

    SET @count = @count - 1;
END
```

Answer (score 0):

While I agree with the others that there is likely a better way to achieve what you are trying to do, if there is some limitation that we are not seeing, you could look into using a [sequence](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff878058.aspx)

The sequence you create persists and can be reset as needed and you can "increment" it by calling the `NEXT VALUE FOR` function